# Remove item from json array using its random ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, array-splice

I have an array which contains values as follows:

```
{
"123456": {
    "name": "tom",
    "projects": {
        "987654": {
        "cli": "abcd",
        "org": "123456",
        "cli_e": "abcd",
        "pro": "abcd",
        "status": "6"
        }
      }
   }
},
{
"654321": {
    "name": "jerry",
    "projects": {
        "123": {
        "cli": "xyz",
        "org": "000",
        "cli_e": "xyz",
        "pro": "xyz",
        "status": "3"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I want output to be like below:

```
{
  "cli": "abcd",
  "org": "123456",
  "cli_e": "abcd",
  "pro": "abcd",
  "status": "6"
},
{
  "cli": "xyz",
  "org": "000",
  "cli_e": "xyz",
  "pro": "xyz",
  "status": "3"
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried this: `data['123456'].projects['987654']`?

Comment: Can you flesh out the question a bit more ? Are you saying 123456 is random and you won't know the "name" of the first item in the object ? Otherwise if you know the property names, then VisioN's answer will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer by `hsz`

```
var output = [];
for (var k in input) {
  for (var kk in input[k].projects) {
    output.push(input[k].projects[kk]);
  }
}
```